# Maker-Checker functionality for asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm creating a maker-checker functionality where, maker creates a record and it is reviewed by the checker. The record creation will not happen until the checker approves it. If the checker rejects it then it should be rolled back.

The idea which i know is create a temporary table of records which will hold the records to be created until the checker approves it. But this method will have 2X number of tables to be created to cover all functionalities.

What are the best practices to achieve this?
Is it something which can be done using Windows Work Flow.? (WWF)

Comment: why don't you make a single table with a VerifierID column that remain null until a verifier verify it.

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh But if the record is modified and the checker rejects it. In this case, the record needs to be rolled back and which is not possible if we maintain a single table.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a few more columns to your db.

- Status : Current status of record ( Waiting for approval, Approved,
  Declined . etc)
- Maker : Username or id
- Checker : Username or id
- Checker Approval/Rejection Time

Alternatively if you have lots of tables like this needs to maker/checker workflow you can add another table and reference all other record to this table.

Windows workflow foundation also could work for you but i persnoally find it difficult to use

If you want revisions for the recored you also need more columns. Such as Revision Number and IsLastRevision.

I dont know what you are using for accessing db  and modifiying records. If you are using OR/M you might override  Update and do revisions on all saves . For Example

```
void Update(Entity e )
{
 Entity n = new Entity();
  // Create a copy of e ( With AutoMapper for example or manually )
 e.Current = true;
 e.RevisionNumber += 1;
 Update(e);
 Insert(n);

}
```

Comment: But if the record is modified and the checker rejects it. In this case, the record needs to be rolled back and which is not possible if we maintain a single table.

Comment: @Chandu-Indyaah If the record changed ? The application must ensure that checker is reviewing what maker send for his/her approval. In this case one can say " what about dba, who can change record" ?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you will have two options:

Create two identical tables and use one table for approved data and one for requested data.

OR

You can create two rows for a user with TypeID(requested/approved). in this case user will create a request with typeID = requested when approver approved that request you simply override current approved record with new one otherwise simply mark requested row with rejected status.